# Ubuntu nginx does't run php

Tags: php, nginx

I used to use `lnmp`. Now I decide to use an upgradable apt source. I have build MySQL and Nginx. After installing PHP and `php-fpm`, my nginx cannot execute PHP. It can resolve HTML. Here is my config for my virtual host:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name himeki.net;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   root /home/wwwroot;
   index index.html index.php index.htm;
   location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }
}

server {
   listen 443;
   server_name himeki.net;
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/himeki.net.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/himeki.net.key;
   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
   ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
   ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   root /home/wwwroot;
   location ~ / {
      index index.html index.php index.html index.htm;
   }

   location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$)
           {
               try_files $uri =404;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               include fastcgi.conf;
           }
}
```

Comment: Both SSLv2 and SSLv3 are very vulnerable and should no longer ever be used. You would also want to listen on IPv6 (ie. `listen [::]:80` and `listen [::]:443`)

Comment: OK, I'll try to do that. For now, I just want to enable `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use 'Apache2' to instead. It works.